# Multiple inboxes in Gmail without default inbox

Tags: gmail

I have two email addresses, `user@gmail.com` and `user@university.edu`.

I have set up Gmail's Multiple Inboxes, with the following criteria:

```
University --> label:(university inbox)
gmail --> label:(inbox -university)
```

This gives me two complementary sections, where archiving will also remove the email from my inbox page (which is what I'd like).

However, I still have a third section in my inbox, which contains both `University` and `Gmail`. Is there a way to remove this section?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you could remove it, but you can auto-archive everything that comes in and then it'll only show up in your other inboxes.

Answer (score 0):

under settings/multiple inboxes  there is the `Extra panels positioning` section.

You can specify:

- Right side of the inbox
- Above the inbox
- Below the inbox

setting above the inbox will force the main inbox to the bottom, below the extra inboxes, where it will be less noticeable.

Note: if you do this, the gear icon appears at the top of the main inbox section, you will have to scroll down and find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the horizontal split then you can switch from multiple inboxes feature to priority inbox:

```
university label --> deliveredto:user@university.edu OR __additional_rule_here__
primary label --> has:nouserlabels
```

Labels are applied to messages, not conversations. That's why you need this `__additional_rule_here__` above which must match all the following messages inside conversation. Examples: `from:user@university.edu` or `subject:"_ac_"` where `_ac_` is a special prefix prepended to subject by your email server, mailing list or a google group (`[ac]` or `:ac:` won't work because `[]:` are special symbols that are ignored in a search query if I get it right).

Then in the inbox settings:

1. All primary (shows all messages with `primary` label)
2. Empty
3. Empty
4. Everything else

When creating filters it may be useful to apply it to all existing emails.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue. I found the addon [Click to remove element](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/click-to-remove-element/jcgpghgjhhahcefnfpbncdmhhddedhnk/related?hl=en) that allows you to temporarily or permanently remove elements from websites. I used it to remove the default inbox section in the bottom of my multiple inbox permanently.